# Maintain Redux state from popup to main window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm using auth0 to authenticate my users. When my user selects a provider, it opens a popup so that he can select an account to sign in with.

Now, using the Auth0 sdk, I can fetch my user informations from the provider (email, name, etc...). This all happens in the component that is displayed within my popup.

The following just retrieves an array of informations, and works just fine.

```
[...]
            authenticationService.webAuth.client.userInfo(
                authResult.accessToken,
                (err2: any, user: any) => {
                    this.props.userActions.fetchProviderProfile(user);
                });
```

The matching action:

```
import actions from './redux.actions';
import { authenticationService, restApi, routerHistory } from '../injector';
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';
import { AuthTokens } from '../service/AuthenticationTokensService';
import { Routes } from './../routes/ApplicationRoutes';

const initialState: UserState = {
    currentUser: undefined,
    users: new Map()
};

let userActions = {
    fetchProviderProfile: (profile) => (dispatch: (action: any) => void) => {
        dispatch({
            type: actions.user.prefillUser,
            profile
        });
    }
};

export default userActions;

export const userReducer = (state = initialState, action: any) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actions.user.prefillUser:
            return { ...state, currentUser: action.profile };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

And my store:

```
export const reduxStore = createStore(
    combineReducers({
        userState: userReducer,
        companyState: companyReducer,
        routing: routerReducer,
        form: formReducer
    }),
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, routerMiddleware(routerHistory)),
        devTools
    )) as Store<ApplicationState>;
```

If I inpect my state after executing this piece of code, I see that all datas are correctly stored in state.

Now, the tricky part: once the datas are fetched, I'd like to put them in my application state, close the popup, and then refresh my main window. As I said, they appear in the state if I inspect the popup, BUT do not appear in the main window state (Using Chrome redux tools).

So I thought, maybe I'd have to reload the main window to see if state has changed, but, when using `window.opener.location.reload();` , the page refreshes before all datas are fetched, hence my state is still empty.

How can I maintain my state from popup to main window, even when closing the popup that fetches the datas ?

Comment: With `location.reload()` you are only able to store data somewhere in localStorage or cookies.

Comment: I know, but I thought state was supposed to be maintained, even after a reload ?

Comment: No, the state is only maintained in that instance of your web-app. When you open a new window (such as the popup) that is a different instance of the web-app. If you want to share state between instances it has to be in localStorage or on a server.

Answer (score 0):

You should dispatch an action that will update your redux store via a reducer.
e.g. in your popup component you would do something like this:

```
this.props.dispatch(setAuthData(data))
```

you should have an action-creator called `setAuthData` which will be handled by some reducer to update the state.

If your main app is `connected` (see [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux)) it will update automatically so you really shouldn't perform a whole page reload.

Comment: @PierreOlivierTran can you share your reducer and store code?

Comment: what is the `popup` state you mention? I would trace the dispatch of my action - does it reach the reducer?